# Не срабатывают триггеры ORACLE BD

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, триггер

Делаю БД с таблицами товары и группы товаров. 5 триггеров нормально работают, а 2 из них вообще не срабатывают, хотя по логике там все правильно. Не срабатывают UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL и DELETE_GROUP_C_RETAIL,хотя срабатывает INSERT_GROUP_C_RETAIL,написанный по точно такой же логике. В приоритетах тоже нет проблемы, я пробовал и after и before. Они все равно не срабатывают. То есть при добавлении товара сводная стоимость в группе обновляется, а при изменении входной стоимости товара, сводная стоимость группы не пересчитывается, при удалении тоже не пересчитывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Полный код:

```
CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."PRODUCT_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GROUP_ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENTRY_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "RETAIL_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("GROUP_ID")
      REFERENCES "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL" 
AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE product_group
    SET c_retail = c_retail - (:OLD.retail_price * :NEW.count) + (:NEW.retail_price * :NEW.count)
    WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL" ENABLE;

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_DELETE" 
BEFORE DELETE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Уменьшаем "count" в группе товаров на значение "count" удаляемого товара
  UPDATE product_group
  SET count = count - :OLD.count
  WHERE id = :OLD.group_id;

END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_DELETE" ENABLE;

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ENTRY_PRICE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    v_markup product_group.markup%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    -- Получаем наценку на группу товара
    SELECT markup
    INTO v_markup
    FROM product_group
    WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;

    -- Вычисляем розничную цену
    :NEW.retail_price := :NEW.entry_price * (1 + v_markup);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      -- Если группа товара не найдена
      :NEW.retail_price := 0;
  END;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" ENABLE;

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF COUNT ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Обновляем "COUNT" в группе товаров внутри блока транзакции
   IF UPDATING THEN
   UPDATE product_group  SET count = count-:OLD.count+:NEW.count WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
   ELSE 
   UPDATE product_group  SET count = count+:NEW.count WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
   END IF;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT" ENABLE;

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."INSERT_GROUP_C_RETAIL" 
AFTER INSERT ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE product_group
    SET c_retail = c_retail + (:NEW.retail_price * :NEW.count)
    WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."INSERT_GROUP_C_RETAIL" ENABLE;

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."DELETE_GROUP_C_RETAIL" 
AFTER DELETE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE product_group
    SET c_retail = c_retail - (:NEW.retail_price * :NEW.count)
    WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."DELETE_GROUP_C_RETAIL" ENABLE;


  CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."GROUP_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "C_RETAIL" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "MARKUP" NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_CHK1" CHECK (markup >= 0 AND markup <= 1
) ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" 
AFTER UPDATE OF MARKUP ON product_group
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Обновляем розничные цены в таблице "Товары" для соответствующей группы
  UPDATE product
  SET retail_price = entry_price * (1 + :NEW.markup)
  WHERE group_id = :NEW.id;

END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" ENABLE;
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не работают? Триггер либо работает, либо фэйлит всю транзакцию. У вас я вижу несколько триггеров с обновлением одного и того же поля. Похоже, тот, кто срабатывает второй, перетирает старания первого.

Comment: Потому что сводная стоимость не меняется. Да и как может сработать delete триггер, если я только обновляю значения входной стоимости.

Comment: То что у вас цифры не меняются, не значит, что значения не меняются. Может меняются на то же самое. Добавьте dbms_output в ваши триггеры и посмотрите, где что и когда будет вывываться и с какими значениями. Сразу увидите, какой тригер при какой операции будет запущен.

Comment: А все, я просто триггер целиком на товар повесил,а не на поле entry price. Ну и в delete триггере поменял на after и сделал Old значения,а не new. Заработало. Вообщем,спасибо